# Pandas - Splitting rows with multiple values into new row

Tags: pandas

I have a Dataframe of one column. Some of the rows have multiple value separated by a comma. I would like to have each row have only one value.

Given below is how my Dataframe looks like :

```
0,apples
1,bananas
2,oranges,kiwis
```

Expected output:

```
apples
bananas
oranges
kiwis
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up example:

```
Import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Apples", "bananas", "oranges, kiwis"})
```

Using `.split()`

```
df = df.apply(lambda r: r[0].split(','), axis=1)
```

Now you need this in a list, you can use a for loop, but I like list comprehensions:

```
dlist = [item for row in df for item in row]
```

Now you can use the list to make a new dataframe:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(dlist)
```